# Error in deploy: Package may not be larger than 1073741824 bytes

Tags: deployment, e-commerce, ibm-cloud, devops

I'm trying to run this ecommerce project on Bluemix: 
https://github.com/dtsato/loja-virtual-devops

After fork it with jazz hub and obtain success in build stage, I got a package limit size error in the deploy stage:

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Updating app loja-virtual-devops in org PFC Devops / space test as ricardo.zalla@imejunior.com.br...
OK

Using route loja-virtual-devops-App-Zalla.mybluemix.net
Uploading loja-virtual-devops...
Uploading app files from: /home/pipeline/47cbfb23-f83f-4ec3-b283-fc6c2b7da21f
Uploading 1.4G, 7856 files

148.4M uploaded...
289.3M uploaded...
454M uploaded...
621.3M uploaded...
745.1M uploaded...
906.9M uploaded...
1.1G uploaded...
1.3G uploaded...

Done uploading
FAILED
Error uploading application.
The app package is invalid: Package may not be larger than 1073741824 bytes

Finished: FAILED
```

Any hint about how can I overcome it and successfully run the app without deleting  project files to shrink its size? Is possible to deploy projects larger than 1073741824 bytes on Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude unnecessary files using “.cfignore” and Ignore local node_modules .

Also, Instead of packaging all dependencies, install them during app staging by using a custom buildpack.

Hope this helps.